# unregisterReceiver(receiver) in onPause causes the receiver not to register

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Hello fellow overflowers. I have a problem with a BroadcastReciever - there are, I know a multitude of questions and answers exist because I have been trying each one for the last 2 days so please if you do want to mark this as a duplicate check that the code doesn't match what I've already written (as I have almost certainly copied it form a SO answer).

And so here we go:

I want to detect the lock screen being turned on or off in my base activity - from which all my other activities extend

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{////
```

in here I have member variables

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
IntentFilter filter;
```

which I assign like this:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                        //do some code
                    } else {
                       //do something else
                    }
                }
            };


filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
```

This works as expected if I put it in `onCreate()` or in `onResume()` and I can successfully call `registerReceiver(receiver, filter)` in either create or resume and it works fine.

I don't want this to be active when the app is paused, so as all the various answers and tutorials suggest I unregister it in onPause

```
     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
//I have commented both out to demonstrate that I have tried both before and after the calling the superclass
      //    this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            super.onPause();
    //      unregisterReceiver(receiver);

        }
```

When I include this unregister call it stops the registration from ever happening.  I have tried registering in onCreate,onResume and both.  I can move around the combination all through the activity but as soon as I introduce the unregister it doesn't work at all - not even an error or a crash (otherwise I would include a stack trace here).

The closes thing I have been able to achieve is:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
  //do some code 
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

by putting the unregister into the onRecieve I am am able to deregister the receiver and re-register it correctly, EXCEPT that if I have multiple activities in the stack for my app I get a memory leak error and the trace requests, rather patronisingly if I have forgotten to add an unregister call.

So has anyone any idea why adding the unregister call to the onPause() would cause the receiver to cancel altogether?

Comment: did you try unregistering in `onStop()`?

Comment: when you register in onResume and unregister in onPause, did you receive ACTION_SCREEN_OFF ?

Comment: @H.Taras - if I have not included the unregister in onPause, I do receive ACTION_SCREEN_OFF/ON in onResume, but if I include the unregister call in onPause then I never receive anything at all

Comment: @y.allam - yes I have tried with no success, but all the advice/documentation says not to reply on onStop as it may not be called if the system decides to trim the memory

Comment: @jameson2012 I think, problem is, that system send action screen off after onPause, and action screen on before onResume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought, you have this issue because system sends ACTION_SCREEN_OFF after `onStop()` method, so you can not handle it, because you already unregistered it. Don't know why you can not handle SCREEN_ON event, because when I tested this, I see that system send it after `onResume()`. This is what I have in my logs:

```
D/TEST: onPause:
D/TEST: onStop:
D/TEST: onReceive: action = android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
D/TEST: onStart:
D/TEST: onResume:
D/TEST: onReceive: action = android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

I think, it was sent earlier than `onResume` called, but delivered after it.

So, my solution is to register receiver in `onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` and unregister in `onDestroy()`, that is how I got this logs.

**Update 1:** This is how I registered receiver in `onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(new TestReceiver(), filter);
```

**Update 2:** I missed, that you don't need to receive events if your activity is paused.  If there is some code that you don't want to execute when activity is paused, I can suggest you to create simple enum:

enum ActivityState {
    STARTED, RESUMED, PAUSED, STOPPED
}

and private variable `ActivityState currentState`. Then in lifecycle methods assign proper state to currentState. Then in your receiver `onReceive()` method you can check current state and do what you want depend on state.
Logs when app is in active:

```
D/TEST: onReceive: action = android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF, current Activity state = STOPED
D/TEST: onReceive: action = android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON, current Activity state = RESUMED
```

And logs when app was not active:

```
D/TEST: onReceive: action = android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF, current Activity state = STOPED
D/TEST: onReceive: action = android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON, current Activity state = STOPED
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest delaying unregister for some times and I tried for 1 second and it's working.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    registerReceiver(broadcast, IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
        addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
    })
}


override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    Handler().postDelayed({
        unregisterReceiver(broadcast)
    }, 1000)
}
```